# `sass` throw error on using braces in css

Tags: angular, sass

I am trying to add a property like this:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

but angular cli throw an error. I heard that we can use the `sass` like regular `css` any one help me to sort this?

this is working without any issue:

```
body 
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid red;
```

Comment: Your linting is probably misguiding you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the newer `scss` syntax: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax

To enable this with the `angular-cli`, run this: `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`.

Answer (score 1):

In `sass` no need to add braces ,use it like this

```
body 
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid red;
```

Yes, you can use any regular `css` into `sass` but there are some rules for the same like you don't need to add braces.
But if you are using scss you can use braces as well.

Comment: I agree. But if I use, Is that a problem, this is fully optional right?

Comment: No, this is not optional. There is problem if you use braces in sass

Comment: you can refer for more information https://responsivedesign.is/articles/difference-between-sass-and-scss/